Hard PreCalculus Problems
My AP PreCalc students are ready to tackle problems a bit harder than the usual fare in textbooks and AP Calc practice books.  Are there any books, materials, or websites which have harder PreCalc problems? I don't want to get into Analysis or really high level math. Just unusual problems on the topics covered in an AP PreCalc class.
Thank you so much!

Please note: I've added more resources to my answer. (Geometry!)

Art of Problem Solving was originally designed for competition-level math study. You might find lots of the problems you're looking for in their Precalculus textbook. To check out their style, you can go to their free one-at-a-time problems on their Alcumus site.
You might find other gems on this British site (Math Assessment Project), although it looks more like projects than one-off problems. I also loved some of the problems I found at this site: Rich Starting Points. In the UK that term is used for open-ended investigative activities, and an online search will find you lots of other sites if you like this style of problem.
Also, you can check out competition problems. Here's archives of past AMC10 and AMC12 exams from the AOPS site. Also, AMATYC (American Mathematical Association of Two-Year Colleges) has archives here for their Student Mathematics League Competition. There are lots of other competitions. I'm sure you can find other archives of past exams.
Also, I later realized how valuable geometry problems are in a class at this level. Learning to think visually is so important. My favorite resources for those include Geometry Snacks and More Geometry Snacks, both by Ed Southall and Vincent Pantaloni. Some of these are plenty challenging. If your students want even more challenging geometry problems, check out Catriona Shearer's amazing work (added bonus blog post glowing about her problems).

How about this: $e^{i\theta} = \cos (\theta)+i \sin (\theta)$. Take that as basic and see how far you can go. Derive everything you can from it. Start with showing
$$ \cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta} \right) \ \ \& \ \ 
\sin \theta = \frac{1}{2i} \left( e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta} \right) $$
Show $e^{is}e^{it} = e^{i(s+t)}$ then use it and the identities above to derive just about any trigonometric identity. Then turn to cosh and sinh and explore the analogy between these two worlds since
$$ \cosh \theta = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{\theta}+e^{\theta} \right) \ \ \& \ \ 
\sin \theta = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{\theta}-e^{-\theta} \right) $$
Look at graphs of $y=cosh(x)$ and $y = sinh(x)$. Grapple with understanding why $y = tanh(x)$ has horizontal tangents of $y = \pm 1$. Take a step away from canned problems and try discussion discovery for a change.

If you just want hard problems that are in the topic, my advice is to look at harder algebra 2 or trig books for problems involving lots of algebraic manipulation to derive or prove identities or simplify expressions. It's high bang for the buck in terms of the algebra skills used in calculus. And is on topic.
I do wish you'd consider adding content if you have strong students.  You don't need to become a Rudin lover. But the ironic thing about AP precalculus is that it has significant remedial algebra 2 aspects. And that it omits a lot of traditional precalculus topics.  Manipulation of inequalities. Analytic geometry. And introductory calculus itself.
The quite good public school systems where I live actually see it as a step backwards in terms of rigor from their normal class. And unsuitable for juniors planning to take BC senior year.
But I would even be wary of taking my advice here. Generally stick to the plan and don't get yourself in trouble by going rogue.
However, if you have strong students I completely understand their complaints about AP precalculus. It really is, on purpose, meant to be easier than a traditional precalc course. Joanne Boaler and inclusion driven. I kid you not. It is not a souped up course but a watered down one. E.g. it assumes kids didn't learn logs in algebra 2!
